# Revenue share contract w merged company

Tags: contract-law

Company A developed Product A and has a revenue sharing agreement with Partner A (who sold Product A) to Client A. The revenue sharing agreement is open ended, i.e. does not expire.

Enters Company B with Product B. Product A and Product B are essentially the same with  Product B being a newer version of Product A.

Company B acquires Company A who agrees to merge with Company B, with Company B being the surviving company. Company B intends to kill Product A and offer Product B instead to Client A.

Question -  what happens to the revenue share agreement with Partner A - does Partner A have the right to continue to invoice Company B for its revenue share... given that Product A was discontinued?

Comment: It depends on the contract between company A and partner A.  This is why you want to have lawyers who know the subject matter write your contracts -- they will anticipate such things.

Answer (score 2):

### It depends on the contracts

**The "merger"**

Partner A has no contract with Company B, only with Company A. Therefore, Company B has no rights or obligations towards Partner A unless they are part of the merger or acquisition of Company A. So, there are two contracts that need to be considered, the original one between Partner A and Company A and the merger contract between Company B and Company A.

If the merger contract does not assign or novate the original contract from Company A to Company B, then Company B has no contract with Partner A. They can safely ignore Partner A.

If the original contract is [assignable](https://feldman.law/news/what-happens-to-contracts-after-business-is-sold/#:%7E:text=When%20a%20transaction%20closes%2C%20the,process%20for%20each%20existing%20agreement.) (the default position) and the merger contract makes that assignment (either with reference to the particular contract or in general with all ongoing contracts), then Company B has assumed the rights and obligations of the contract with Person A as a successor-in-interest. At the same time, Company A remains liable for the obligations under the contract if Company B defaults. That is, if Person A is wronged under the contract, they can sue Company A or Company B, or both.

If the contract is not assignable, it must be novated. this substitutes Company B for Company A as if they had always been a party to the contract. However, Person A has to agree to the novation. Such an agreement may already be in the original contract.

There are some contracts, notably personal services contracts, that are neither assignable nor novatable. In this case, a new contract would need to be negotiated.

Whatever happens, the merger will not end the contract - Person A will still have a contract with Company A *or* Company B. If it is an actual merger rather than an acquisition, there will be a new Company C that might hold the contract. Notwithstanding, there is still a contract between someone and Person A.

**The original contract**

> Question - what happens to the revenue share agreement with Partner A - does Partner A have the right to continue to invoice Company B for its revenue share... given that Product A was discontinued?

Depends on what the contract says about discontinuing Product A.

While the contract, as described, is indefinite, I doubt very much if it is perpetual. Hopefully, the people who drafted the original contract dealt with the very realistic contingency that Company A (or whoever now holds the contract) might want to stop selling Product A. After all, no product keeps being sold forever. If so, then do what the contract says.

If it doesn't, then Company A (or whoever) is probably under no obligation to a) continue to sell Product A and b) pay Person A if they aren't.